# Ruby - arrays check for and replace with

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, loops, replace

Given:

```
check_for = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]

replace_with = ["Donec", "ut", "libero", "sed", "arcu"]

sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur."
```

How can I check the entire string in 'sentence' if it contains the words placed in the array 'check_for' and if they are found, replace with the words in 'replace_with'?

Words in check_for can be replaced with words in replace_with with the same index:

check_for[idx] should be replaced with replace_with[idx]

I've done something "similar" with Javascript using nested loops. For some reason this isn't working with Ruby.

My idea with nested loops was to split sentence into array and using while loops with i and j. So sentence[i] would start at 0:

```
sentence[i] == check_for[j]
```

then:

```
sentence[i] = replace_with[j]
```

Aside from this idea not working, I'm certain there is a more straight forward way in Ruby.

Case insensitive is ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That could be done with a hash defining the replacements:

```
sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
replacements = {
  'Lorem' => 'Donec',
  'ipsum' => 'ut',
  'dolor' => 'libero',
  'sit'   => 'sed',
  'amet'  => 'arcu',
}

sentence.gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)
#=> "Donec ut libero sed arcu, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
```

Btw you can easily generate that `replacements` hash from your arrays like this:

```
replacements = Hash[check_for.zip(replace_with)]
```

---

Cary Swoveland suggested to use a simplified Regexp:

```
sentence.gsub(/\w+/, replacements)
```

And I really like that, because it reads much nicer.

I wondered if the rexexp has an impact on performance: On the one side building a complex but specialised regexp. On the other side using a simple regexp but have to check each word against the hash.

```
require 'benchmark'

def simple
  @sentence.gsub(/\w+/, @replacements)
end

def union
  @sentence.gsub(Regexp.union(@replacements.keys), @replacements)
end

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bmbm(15) do |x|
  x.report("simple :")   { n.times do; simple; end }
  x.report("union  :")   { n.times do; union ; end }
end

# Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
# simple :          4.790000   0.010000   4.800000 (  4.804576)
# union  :          3.820000   0.020000   3.840000 (  3.846012)
# ------------------------------------------ total: 8.640000sec
```

Turns out that the longer version is a bit faster. But I am pretty sure that might change depending on the length of `sentence` and the number of elements to replace.

Comment: You could also write `sentence.gsub(/\w+/, replacements)`, as only words that match a hash key will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without a replacement hash, using the [`#index` method](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index):

```
replaced_sentence = []
sentence.split.each do |word|

  if idx = check_for.index(word.match(/\w+/).to_s) 
    replaced_sentence << word.gsub((/\w+/) , replace_with[idx] )
    else
     replaced_sentence << word
    end
 end

replaced_sentence.join(' ')
#=> "Donec ut libero sed amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
```

This iterates through each word of the sentence.  If `check_for` contains the word (minus punctuation), `check_for.index(word...)` returns that index value. Then that index value is assigned to `idx`, and the value of `replace_with[idx]` replaces the word and is "pushed" to the new `replaced_sentence` array.

If there's no match for the word,  `check_for.index(word)` returns `nil`, which causes the `if` statement to not hold true, and the original `word` gets pushed to the new array.

Comment: I went with spikermann's method but I really like this. Even though it's still different than my nested loop idea, this is pretty much what I had in mind.

Comment: I realized my solution did not account for punctuation.  I now need to use a small RegEx.  I've updated my answer.